# c# winform, object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have checkbox in my DataGridView to delete one or multiple rows from my DataGridView already loaded data from database. DataSource is dataBindingSource.
I want to check first if the user checked one or multiple checkboxes and here is my code to check.

```
int total = dgvRegister.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells["Delete"].Value) == true).Count();
if (total > 0)
{
// Do something

}
```

But I'am geting this error "object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types". I have gogled  but not s omuch to help.
Please help me to solv this problem and thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the hole code

```
private void btnDeActivateComputers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (CompEntities db = new CompEntities())
            {
                if (dgvRegister.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int total = dgvRegister.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells["Delete"].Value) == true).Count();
                    if (total > 0)
                    {
                         
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete?", "Deleting", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            for (int i = dgvRegister.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                            {
                                DataGridViewRow row = dgvRegister.Rows[i];
                                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Delete"].Value) == true)
                                {
                                    int ComId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRegister.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                                    var deletecomp = db.Comp.Where(x => x.ComId == cId).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (deletecomp != null)
                                    {
                                        db.Comp.Remove(deletecomp);


                                    }


                                    db.SaveChanges();

                                }
                            }
                        }


                        

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Check at least one checkbox !", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    }
                }
                 
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
            while (inner != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(inner.Message);
                inner = inner.InnerException;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: `var count = dgvRegister.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Count(row => row.Cells["Delete"].Value != DBNull.Value && (bool)row.Cells["Delete"].Value);` -- It's not clear what *delete one or multiple rows from my DataGridView as I load data from database* means. Delete as you load? You mean remove Rows from the source of data? Is this a sort of merge operation? Why are you looping the Rows of the Grid then?

Comment: @Jimi thank you for responding. No I have alrady loaded from database to Datagridview.  From those multiple Columns I have one with checkbox ther I check those rows to delete.

Comment: You need to be more specific. E.g., what is the DataSource of your DGV set to? Add this information and anything else relevant to the body of your question.

Comment: @Jimi, It is dataBindingSource

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken, so… you want to delete the rows from the grid that have the check box cell “checked?” … If this is the case then your current posted code, even if it worked… is not going to help you. The code gets the “count” of the number of check boxes that have been checked. This ONLY tells “how many” are checked? It does not tell you “Which” rows are checked. You should be gathering a list/array/collection of the row “INDEXES” that have the check box checked. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: As mentioned, add any further information to the question -- Anyway, if you want to **remove** Rows, you need to remove them from the source of data, or - since you're using a BindingSource (it appears) - from the internal List : e.g., `[BindingSource].List.OfType<DataRowView>().Where(r => r.Row["Delete"] != DBNull.Value && (bool)r.Row["Delete"]).ToList().ForEach(row => [BindingSource].Remove(row));` -- This assuming the source of data is a DataTable; otherwise, use the actual Type <= that's why you need to add the missing information...

Comment: @Jimi , I just want to check how many checkboxses are checked.  Iwant to message the user that they have first to checked ast least one row or one chexkbox.

Comment: @JohnG I just want to check how many checkboxses are checked.  Iwant to message the user that they have first to checked at least one row or one chexkbox.

Comment: Then see my first comment.

Comment: @Jimi , I don't know why but I get the same error

Comment: Have I mentioned that **you need to specify what the source of data is** and also to **add this information to the question**?

Comment: @Jimi, yes I did. It's dataBindingSource

Comment: How are you “adding” the check box column to the grid? In other words, IS the check box column attached to the grid’s `DataSource/BindingSource`? Or is it “independent” and is NOT part of the underlying data source? It would NOT be unusual for the check box column to be “independent” since it is just part of the UI and NOT some data that you would typically save. Can you clarify how the check box column is added to the grid?

Comment: There is no `dataBindingSource` Type, you mean a `BindingSource`. That's not the source of data, that's the mediator. Your BindingSource also has a DataSource, that's the source of data.

Comment: @Jimi , I have another datagridview as right now working and when I checked "sort a DataGridView programmatically" for just that checkbox it's Notsortble and working, but with this datagrid tha tI have problem with ..When I try to change from programmatically to NotSortable, it changes automaticaly to programmatically . Is ther any code to write in load_form to change to "NotSortable" ?

Comment: Note that if you're still trying to loop the Rows of the Control instead of the source of the Rows and you have `AllowUsersToAddRows = true`, then you're also looping the DGV's `NewRow`, which will give you a `NuReferenceException` in this context. -- Sortable or not sortable is not the problem: as mentionend, you should perform this check on the source of data (or the BindingSource), not the grid. See my 3rd comment about that. -- This if, as JohnG mentioned, the CheckBox Column is generated by the data source. <= Most of the required information is still missing.

Comment: @Jimi, Now I have the hole code. Check my update please. Thank you for your efforts

Comment: @Jimi , sorry I missed to save changs. But now you can see the hole code. Thank you again

Comment: @JohnG , Now I have uppdated my code, you can se the hole code, thnak you again

Comment: Please re-read Jimi’s first comment. Whenever you check a cells `Value` like… `x.Cells["Delete"].Value` … or … `row.Cells["Delete"].Value` … there is a good chance that `Value` will be `null`. There could be several reasons why the cell `Value` is `null`… but the point is that you MUST check to see if `Value` is `null` BEFORE you try to use it. Your code NEVER checks for this `null` `Value` and it should to avoid the crashes you are getting now. Specifically, it looks like the `Convert` will throw up this error if you pass it a `null` value. I suggest you use a `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @Jimi , I want to thank you for your eforts. I found the problem, in my database delete proporty was as Null, not as False. When I changed them to False, then it works now as it is. I don't know why. but I want realy to thank you the way you tried to describe and help.

Comment: @JohnG, I want to thank you to you too for your eforts. I found the problem, in my database delete proporty was as Null, not as False. When I changed them to False, then it works now as it is. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern to following using Entity Framework Core and C#9, some adjustments are needed if using say .NET Framework 4.8 but the principles are the same as noted below.

Model `Categories` where `Checked` property is not part of the underlying table.`[NotMapped]` tells Entity Framework to exclude this property while `[DefaultValue(false)]` provides false as the default value.

```
public class Categories
{
    [NotMapped]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

In the form, create a `BindingSource` which is used for all operations once assigned as the DataSource to the DataGridView. As mentioned in various comments, there is zero need to reference data via the DataGridView.

**Notes**

- Code is C#9, minor adjustments will be needed if not using .NET Core.
- In the button to remove records a lambda statement is used to get checked items
- A wrapper for MessageDialog is used to ask permission to remove data
- A class is provided to where you would remove the records but doesn't actually remove records, you need to write that code.
- DataGridView columns were created in the DataGridView designer and each column DataPropertyName set to properties from the model

Form code with two classes that belong in their own files.

```
namespace StackoverflowCodeSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            Shown += OnShown;

        }

        private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using var context = new NorthwindContext();

            _bindingSource.DataSource = context.Categories.ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;

        }

        private void GetCheckedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var checkedCategories =
                ((List<Categories>)_bindingSource.DataSource)
                .Where(category => category.Checked)
                .ToList();


            if (checkedCategories.Count > 0)
            {
                /*
                 * Prompt to remove selected entities
                 * Remove from database table, save
                 * if save changes is successful
                 *    Remove from BindingSource
                 * else
                 *    inform user of issues
                 */

                if (Dialogs.Question($"Remove {checkedCategories.Count} items?"))
                {
                    var (success, exception) = DataOperations
                        .RemoveRange(checkedCategories);

                    if (success)
                    {
                        for (int index = 0; index < checkedCategories.Count; index++)
                        {
                            _bindingSource.Remove(checkedCategories[index]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"Removal failed with\n{exception.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataOperations
    {
        public static (bool success, Exception exception) RemoveRange(List<Categories> list)
        {
            try
            {
                // remove items here
                // Set each entity state
                // perform SaveChanges
                return (true, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return (false, e);
            }
        }
    }
    public static class Dialogs
    {
        public static bool Question(string text)
        {
            return (MessageBox.Show(
                text,
                "Question",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your response, my god this is beyond my coding knowlage and very complicated for me  :) I found the problem. The problem was that I had NULL in my "Delete" property in my  database. Thank you again